# Localhost install Theme. Problem with 'bin'

Tags: magento2, localhost

I have localhost E:\xampp and i have a problem with 'bin' environment variable

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento index:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that i can suggest you is that:

move into your magento 2 project main folder from your cmd and then run the command with full path to your php.exe file.

```
E:\XAMPP\php\php.exe bin/magento setup:upgrade
E:\XAMPP\php\php.exe bin/magento index:reindex
E:\XAMPP\php\php.exe bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `php` in front of the commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento index:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Also, try to add full path to php if that didn't work:

Run:

```
which php
// example output /usr/bin/php
```

So the commands would look like this now:

```
/usr/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade
/usr/bin/php bin/magento index:reindex
/usr/bin/php bin/magento cache:clean
```